# What is the difference between patches vs patchesJson6902 in Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, patch, json-patch, kustomize

Based on the docs that I've read, there are 3 methods of patching:

- patches
- patchesStrategicMerge
- patchesJson6902.

The difference between `patchesStrategicMerge` and `patchesJson6902` is obvious. `patchesStrategicMerge` requires a duplicate structure of the kubernetes resource to identify the base resource that is being patched followed by the modified portion of the spec to denote what gets changed (or deleted).

`patchesJson6902` defines a 'target' attribute used to specify the kubernetes resource with a 'path' attribute that specifies which attribute in the resource gets modified, added, or removed.

However, what is not clear to me is the difference between `patches` and `patchesJson6902`. They seem to be very similar in nature. Both specify a 'target' attribute and operation objects which describes what gets modified.

The only difference I've noticed is that `patches` does not require a 'group' attribute while `patchesJson6902` does; The reason for this is unknown.

So why the difference between the two? How do I determine which one to use?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The explanation for this is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/2705#issuecomment-659012281).

To summarize, `patchJson6902` is an older keyword which can only match one resource via `target` (no wildcards), and accepts only Group-version-kind (GVK), namespace, and name.

The `patches` directive is newer and accepts more elements (annotation selector and label selector as well). In addition, namespace and name can be regexes. The target for `patches` can match more than one resource, all of which will be patched.

In addition, with `patches`, it will attempt to parse patch files as a Json6902 patch, and if that does not work, it will fall back to attempting the patch as a strategic merge. Therefore, in many cases `patches` can obviate the need of using `patchesStrategicMerge` as well.

Overall, it seems as if `patches` should work pretty universally for new projects.

Upstream documentation for these key words:

- [patches](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patches/)
- [patchesJson6902](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patchesjson6902/)
- [patchesStrategicMerge](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patchesstrategicmerge/)

Comment: How about `patchesStrategicMerge`?

Comment: According to official docs: `The patchesStrategicMerge field was deprecated in v5.0.0.` It's suggested to use `patches`